# Difference between package reload and package refresh?

Tags: webmethod

Can you please help me to find out the main difference between package reload and package refresh in webMethods?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the Package Navigator view, Designer retrieves a fresh copy of the contents of all the packages from the memory of the Integration Server. 
 When you reload a package, Integration Server removes the existing package information from memory and loads new versions of the package and its contents into its memory.